# Is there a way to FreezePanes (on a Pivot Table) in Aspose Cells?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, aspose, aspose-cells

I'm porting a slower-than-molasses-on-the-Ross-Ice-Shelf Excel Interop app to Aspose Cells. One feature I'm trying to port over (can't find the way to do it [here](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Migration+from+Microsoft+Office+Automation+to+Aspose)) is "FreezePanes"

My legacy (Excel Interop) code is commented out; it works; my attempt at an Aspose Cellsisization of it is below that - all I could get was setting the range:

```
private void FreezePanePivotTable(int rowToFreeze, int colToFreeze)
{
    //Range pivotTableCellToFreeze = (Range)_xlPivotTableSheet.Cells[rowToFreeze, colToFreeze];
    //_xlPivotTableSheet.Activate();
    //pivotTableCellToFreeze.Activate();
    //pivotTableCellToFreeze.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;

    // AsposeCells version of the above:
    var pivot = pivotTableSheet.PivotTables[0];
    var dataBodyRange = pivot.DataBodyRange;
    int rowsUsed = dataBodyRange.EndRow;
    int colsUsed = dataBodyRange.EndColumn;

    Range pivotTableCellToFreeze = pivotTableSheet.Cells.CreateRange(
        rowToFreeze, colToFreeze, rowsUsed, colsUsed);
    //pivotTableSheet.ac <= No "activate"
    //pivotTableCellToFreeze.act <= No "activate" here, either
    //pivotTableCellToFreeze.ApplyStyle <= No "Application.etc." etither...
}
```

Is there a way to set up FreezePanes in Aspose Cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this thread and let us know if it resolves your issue and if you are looking for something else.

[Thread Link](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/810370/810456/showthread.aspx#810456)

**Note:** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose